# Refresh model from JSON

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a deeply nested model with one-to-one and one-to-many relationships. Initially I retrieved this model from server using standard ember-data API.

What I need to do now is to update model (and all its relationships) from a plain JSON retrieved by an AJAX call.

I cannot use `reload()` method, because that would make an additional HTTP request - I already have the JSON payload, so no need for an extra HTTP request.

Is there a way to reload a model from JSON?

Comment: You can use [pushPayload](https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload) to add new recors and update the existing records in store.

Comment: @kumkanillam thanks, that helped - do you want to post it as an answer so I can accept it? (btw I needed to revert all old changes on the model before calling pushPayload - otherwise it won't update the model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pushPayload/push` for to add new records and update the existing records in store.

To revert all old changes, You can get all the records from store by peekAll, and iterate it for `hasDirtyAttributes`, if its  true then unload it from store. after that you can use pushPayload to update the incomind records into store.

```
let allRecords = this.get('store').peekAll('modelname')
let dirtiedRecords = allRecords.filterBy('hasDirtyAttributes',true);
dirtiedRecords.forEach((item) =>{
 item.unloadRecord();
});
//after that you can use pushPayload the result you got it from Ajax call.
```

Refer:
https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Model.html#property_hasDirtyAttributes
https://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Enumerable.html#method_filterBy
https://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Store.html#method_pushPayload